# How to get text from header having separator

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

How to fetch text for

```
<h1 _ngcontent-gtj-c13=""> Site-2 
<span _ngcontent-gtj-c13="" class="seprator">|</span> 
Building-1 <!----> </h1>
```

I have used attribute innerhtml,value,outerhtml,javascript
Not able to fetch site name with building name

```
getting text= Site-2 |
expected =  Site-2 | Building-1
```

Comment: <h1 _ngcontent-gtj-c13=""> Site-2 <span _ngcontent-gtj-c13="" class="seprator">|</span> Building-1 <!----> </h1>

Comment: What locators/code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that class attribute value-seprator for span is unique for the page.

First find the parent element of the "span class="seprator" which is h1

```
IWebElement option = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='seprator']//parent::h1"));
```

Now get the innertext of the h1 element using the code.

```
var textinside = option.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

In any software qa company, we can get the locator using any of the 02 ways below:

1. using xpath
2. using css selector

In case the locator is not found using this way, we can use Actions class or JavascriptExecutor in order to locate the element. These are the common practices followed in any quality assurance services.

Once we fetch the locator, we can get the text by using the below code:
findElement(By.cssSelector()).getText()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getText()` method of Selenium's `WebElement` class to get the text of the header element, and then split it by the separator "|" to get the site name and building name separately.

Here's some sample code in java using Selenium WebDriver:

```
WebElement header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@_ngcontent-gtj-c13='']"));
String siteName = header.getText().split(" \\| ")[0];
String buildingName = header.getText().split(" \\| ")[1];
System.out.println("Site name: " + siteName);
System.out.println("Building name: " + buildingName);
```

In this example, we first locate the parent element `h1` using its attribute `_ngcontent-gtj-c13`. Then we use the `getText()` method to get the text content of the parent element, which includes the separator. We split the text using the separator `" | "` to get the site name and building name separately.

The output of this example code would be:

```
Site name: Site-2
Building name: Building-1
```